# fadeIn not working on nth-child(2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Could someone have a look at my code. what it's suppose to do is animate the img tags using fadeIn and fadeOut but it only fades out the first img and doesn't fade in the second img. I think my css could be wrong and that's why the second image isn't showing Im not getting any errors

its an image on top of another image

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.social-media a').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
        $(this).find("img:nth-child(2)").fadeIn();
        $(this).find("img:nth-child(1)").fadeOut()
    });
})
```

HTML

```
<div class="social-media">
    <a title="Share On Twitter" href="#">
         <img alt="" src="images/icon_twitter.png" />
         <img class="test" alt="" src="images/icon_twitter_active.png" />
</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.social-media {
    padding-top: 20px; 
    width: 166px; 
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
}
.social-media a {
    position: relative;
    width: 55px;
    height: 51px;
}
.social-media a img:nth-child(1) {
    opacity: 1;
}
.social-media a img:nth-child(2) {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: -33px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2; 
}
```

Comment: You should consider using CSS sprites... wouldn't that make the implementation a lot easier, as well as making more semantic sense?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hiding the second `<img>` element with zero opacity, you should use `display: none` instead:

```
.social-media a img:nth-child(2) {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: -33px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 2; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8vH4E/

However, I would strongly recommend using a simple CSS image sprite to achieve this effect, which doesn't require JS.

---

**Update:** Since OP asked if it is possible to do with CSS, I have modified the Fiddle to exclude the use of JS and simply rely on the use of CSS and pseudo-elements: http://jsfiddle.net/8vH4E/2/

```
.social-media a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x200);
    background-size: cover;
}
.social-media a::before {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x200/4a7298/eeeeee);
    background-size: cover;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}
.social-media a:hover::before {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

My strategy is rather simple:

- Use background images instead. For sizing, I have used `cover` but you are free to use any sizing (absolute pixel/point sizes, relative percentage sizes or dynamically-computed sizes like `cover`, `contain`)
- For the hover state, use an absolutely-positioned pseudo element that covers the entire `<a>` (by positioning it absolutely and with zero offset from all four directions). We don't need pointer events on the pseudo element, so we set it to `pointer-events: none`
- When the `<a>` element is hovered on (targeted with the `:hover` selector), we toggle the opacity of the pseudo-element from `0` to `1`. We declare the transition property on the pseudo-element to allow for smooth, browser-computed and JS-agnostic transition.

Comment: If I were to do a sprite how do you achive the fadeIn and fadeOut effect if you can show me an example

Comment: Use pseudo-elements instead... that should be quite straight forward. Also, do you want the images to crossfade?

Comment: @KDM Updated my answer :) see the pure CSS solution :D

Answer (score 0):

the sprite is good but does not give smooth fading animation (think that was the main reason, **KDM**, wasn't it?).

So let's fix existing code:

1. as the `fadeOut()` turns the element to the `display: none;` state, as the `fadeIn()` starts working when the element is `display: none;`. So let's turn the 2nd image in `display: none;` first;
2. We can omit the opacity at all for both images (relying on 1.0 as default); `$.fadeIn/Out()` use the opacity from the CSS as the start/end point of the animation. Of course you can set the opacity explicitly for each image if it's designed in such way;
3. `display: inlibe-block;` for the `<a>` is a good point because it contains inline elements which *possibly* can disappear (`display: none;`); that causes the the whole `<a>` disappearing and the `mouseleave` event firing with unexpected UI bugs.

Enjoy http://jsfiddle.net/8vH4E/1/ and thanks to **Terry** for the fiddle :)